# Is it suggested not to import parent's or siblings' class header file in cocos2d?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, cocos2d-iphone, compilation

For example, there're three classes, Aclass, Bclass, and Cclass.
Aclass initializes some instances of Bclass and Cclass as different children. Normally I'll import Bclass.h and Cclass.h in Aclass.h or Alcass.m. So far Bclass and Cclass don't know each other yet. However there're cases for example Bclass needs to know Cclass's properties and methods. One way to do this is to import Cclass.h in Bclass.h or Bclass.m; later on Cclass needs to know about Bclass, then I'll import Bclass.h in Cclass.h or Cclass.m. Sometimes if there's "import cycle" that can't pass the compiling, then I may change one of the import from xx.h into @class Xclass.

Though this works, however I feel it's not the right or delegate way to do. I used to use delegate only to avoid importing parent's class. So what's the best way to design if one class needs to know about it's siblings?

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting import cycles, what you should do is just import the headers into the .m files, then if you really need that object in the .h, use `@class ClassName;` at the top of your header to promise to the compiler that the type of object exists.

edit:
my bad, tl;dr'ed the last sentance, that is the correct way to approach it

Comment: In my understanding, you mean in .m files, you can just import whatever you like, parent class, siblings, import cycles etc, and let the compiler to handle them? It is a common way to do so? I used to use delegate only to avoid importing parent's class.

Comment: yes (but not the part about import cycles), the only time import cycles occur is when two (or more) header files import each other, and the compiler freaks out about it, all header files do at the end of the day is promise other .m files that those set of properties and functions exist somewhere in the code. so having `@class` or it actually imported into the header doesnt make much difference to the compiler in the end so long as its not causing an import cycle (which is sort of like a recursive infinite loop for the compiler)

Comment: Thanks a lot Fonix! The import cycles here is not the right word. I mean in B.m import C.h, and in C.m also import B.h. So it's alright to do whatever import as long as you keep it in .m files. Am I right?

Comment: yep, always safe in the .m files, but if you can i would rather import them in the .h, because if ClassX imports ClassY which imports ClassZ, then ClassX wont need to import ClassZ if its used in ClassX at all, which can save you a bit of hassle.